# Check if files exist, get the most recent one

Tags: command-line, bash, files

If I have these files in my `test` folder

```
ehsant@lp02944:~/test$ll
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 ehsant ehsant 4096 May 19 17:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 ehsant ehsant 4096 May 19 14:45 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 ehsant ehsant    7 May 19 14:53 log.20200519_04
-rw-r--r-- 1 ehsant ehsant    7 May 19 14:54 log.20200519_05
-rw-r--r-- 1 ehsant ehsant    8 May 19 14:55 log.20200519_06
-rw-r--r-- 1 ehsant ehsant    7 May 19 14:56 log.20200519_07
```

Assume current date is 2020/05/19

How can I search for a specific word inside the most recent file which is `log.20200519_07`
My requirement limits me to have the bash command in only 1 line.
I have to first check for the existence of the files with this format `log.$(date +%Y%m%d)_??`
and if I found any, search in the most recent one.

There are different scenarios:

1- There is no file in the folder -> Then do nothing
2- There is only one file in the folder -> Then search in that single file
3- There are more than 1 file in the folder -> Then find the most recent file and search inside that file.

For now I have this command:

```
if [ -e ~/test/log.$(date +%Y%m%d)_?? ]; then ls -tr1 ~/test/log.$(date +%Y%m%d)_?? | tail -1 | xargs grep -q "WARNING"; else exit 123; fi
```

This command works for the first and second scenario but not for the third one.
If the 3 scenario happens, I get `bash: [: too many arguments` error and then it falls to the else clause

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: This kind of thing is simpler is `zsh`, where you can use glob qualifiers to order by modification time and take the first match ex. `log.$(date +%Y%m%d)_??(om[1])`

Comment: Thank @steeldriver but I can not use `zsh` as this command is going to be run internally in another application.

Comment: Last task fails because the glob match returns multiple files and the if -e statement can only handle one file.

Comment: Perhaps the simplest thing would be to set the `nullglob` option - then there's really no need to apply the `-e` test at all

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ls` version sort in a loop instead:

```
$ for i in $(ls -r1v ~/test/log.* 2>/dev/null); do \
  grep -q "WARNING" < "$i" && echo match; break; done
```

Another example using read:

```
$ read -r < <(ls -r1v ~/test/log.* 2>/dev/null) && \
  { grep -q "WARNING" < "$REPLY" && echo match; } || echo file not found.
```

In a script, I prefer to check for existence before using the file.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t -n 1 < <(ls -r1v ~/test/log.* 2>/dev/null)

[[ -e $MAPFILE ]] || \
    { echo file not found.; exit 123; }

grep -q "WARNING" < "$MAPFILE" && echo match || echo no match
```

Comment: Thanks @bac0n , Although your answer is not what I was looking for for couple of reasons: 1- it does not sort files by modified date(I can add a -t to ls for that) 2- it loops through all the files while I just need the most recent file if exist but `2>/dev/null` is the one I was looking for. It helped me write my command.

Comment: Sometimes I use *for* as a lazy set and check for empty, ls -v sorts on the filename instead of the timestamp, and if the dirname is date/well formated it may be preferable. The break should stop the  loop after one iteration

Comment: @EhsanT you should try: `time ( you script here )` and compare them

Comment: OK, but another question, how can I check if the file does not exist? Because with `if` statement, I have an `else` block for that but I don't know with `for` how can I do that? I mean I can encapsulate it in an `if` statement but I don't believe that's the right way do do it

Comment: if *ls* does not find any files then *for* will not have anything to loop :)=

Comment: Yes, but I what if I want to take some actions in the else block? and I've done the time for both of the commands, They are slightly different `real 0m0.007s user 0m0.002s sys 0m0.003s` for my command and `real 0m0.007s user 0m0.002s sys 0m0.002s` for your command. I believe your command is more efficient and uses less resources and I'll keep the use of it in mind, but I still think going with `if` is the more reasonable way in my specific way

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help guys,

I found my answer with your help.

This command worked for me:

```
if [ "$(ls -1 ~/test/log.$(date +%Y%m%d)_?? 2>/dev/null | wc -l)" -gt 0 ]; then ls -tr1 ~/test/log.$(date +%Y%m%d)_?? | tail -1 | xargs grep -q "WARNING"; else exit 123; fi
```

So I'm checking if the number of files is greater than 0 then find the most recent one and grep inside it.

And `2>/dev/null` helped me to bypass `No such file or directory` error in case no file exist in the folder. You can refer to this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/40714363/1908331 for that